# how to get the security group names of a user in azure active directory

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, wif, azure-active-directory

I have referred to other links in the forum and I have the below code which works and gets me the security groups of a particular upn

```
private List<string> GetGroups(string userName)
{
 List<string> result = new List<string>();
 WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(userName);

 foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
 {
     try
     {
         result.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { }
 }
result.Sort();
return result;
}
```

But the same code didn't work for Azure. So  I tried below code which works but I didn't find a way to read security group names the current user has:

```
        var displayName =  ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value ;
        var upn =  ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;
```

Comment: have you checked any documentation ? - http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/ || [MSDN Azure Active Directory Code Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question refers to users authenticated using Windows Integrated Authentication (WIA). When you use Azure AD, you usually are authenticating over the public internet, using authentication protocols like OpenID Connect that operate higher than the network layer. That results in a different representation for the identity of the caller.
Please refer to http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx for guidance and useful links about working with groups in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

Just see your problem, the problem needs memberof attributes to resolve, give  you a sample to help you to find the security group name.

```
  var searchString = "upnname";
        try
        {
           List<IUser> users = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(User => User.UserPrincipalName.StartsWith(searchString)).ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList();
            foreach (IUser user in users)
            {
                IUserFetcher userfetch = user as IUserFetcher;
                IList<Group> groupMembership = new List<Group>();
                IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection =userfetch.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync().Result;

                List<IDirectoryObject> directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
                foreach (IDirectoryObject directoryObject in directoryObjects)
                {
                    if (directoryObject is Group)
                    {
                        var group = directoryObject as Group;
                         if(group.SecurityEnabled.Equals(true))
                        {
                        groupMembership.Add(group);
                        Console.WriteLine("UserPrincinpleName:{0} Group DisplayName:{1}", user.UserPrincipalName, group.DisplayName);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }          
               }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError getting Group {0} {1}",
                e.Message, e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
        }
```

There are some differences in B2C. Keep contact if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string LookupDisplayNameOfAADObject(string objectId)
{
    string objectDisplayName = null;
    string tenantId = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current).
                      FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string signedInUserID = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current).
                            FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    string userObjectID = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current).
                          FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"],
                                                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]);

    // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's EF DB
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
        string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Authority"], tenantId),
        new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));

    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphAPIIdentifier"],
        credential,
        new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    string doQueryUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/directoryObjects/{2}?api-version={3}",
                                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphAPIIdentifier"], tenantId,
                                      objectId,
                                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphAPIVersion"]);

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, doQueryUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content;
        string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var directoryObject = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(responseString);

        if (directoryObject != null) 
        {
            objectDisplayName = string.Format("{0} ({1})", directoryObject.displayName, directoryObject.objectType);
        }

        return objectDisplayName;
    }
}
```